# tkinter state of button for multi-clicks

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, button

I have written a simple code. The button is disabled when process is running and it is enabled after the process finishes. It works as expected for the first time, but when I re-click the button (do not close the window), the button could not be disabled while the process is ok. Can anyone gives some hints.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import threading


win = tk.Tk()


class test(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):

        super(test, self).__init__()


    def run(self):

        print("start !!!")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("end !!!")


def monitor_state(thread):

    if not thread.is_alive():
        btn.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)

    win.after(50, monitor_state, thread)


def py1_go():


    btn.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

    test_thread = test()
    test_thread.setDaemon(True)
    test_thread.start()

    monitor_state(test_thread)



btn = tk.Button(text='Display Results', command = py1_go)
btn.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put the `win.after(50, ...)` inside an `else` statement.

Comment: also try and avoid using `time.sleep` with `tkinter`

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 The `time.sleep` is in the other thread (I think). If it is, it shouldn't interfere with `tkinter` so it should be fine.

Comment: @TheLizzard I just meant to avoid using it in practice. For small programs, it is easy to debug, but for large chunks of code, good practices help debug it faster. Again, just a suggestion

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 I agree that for large projects, `time.sleep` should be avoided as it's rarely needed. I think that OP might have some long calculation but replaced it with `time.sleep` to make a minimal working example.

Comment: It really helpful, thanks

Comment: @TheLizzard， where the  time.sleep locates is really a long calculation (with heavy iterations). However, even I use the multithread, the window does not freeze, but when I try to move the window, the lag still exists.

Comment: @TaoZeng There are 3 things you can do: optimise your code, run a new process instead of a new thread, or get a library like `numpy` do you the calculations. Without knowing more about the code you have there, I can't give any more suggestions.

Comment: @TheLizzard does the second advice means that even if the main part of the code runs in an another thread, it could not fully solve the lag problem (sometimes even freeze  the window)

Comment: @TaoZeng Spawning another thread is useful but sometimes not good enough. If you want more processing time, spawning a new process using the `multiprocessing` library might be useful. I don't know much about that library but I know that it's quite hard to communicate between processes.

Answer (score 0):

A Tkinter `Button` has three states : `active`, `normal`, `disabled`.

Snippet:

```
def run(self):
    print("start !!!")
    btn["state"] = "disabled"
 
    time.sleep(3)
          
    print("end !!!")
    btn["state"] = "normal"
```